# Asking facebook permissions dialog inside iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, permissions

Im trying to put the facebook permissions dialog within an iframe, however not making much progress because of lack of Facebook documentation, and the undocumented hacks around web are not working any more.

news.yahoo.com does something that i would like to emulate.

When you click on a news article it says login with facebook. After the initial oauth dialog to authenticate the user ( which does not ask for permissions), yahoo pop's another dialog from a yahoo URL which included the Permissions dialog within as an IFrame.

Does anybody know what API's can be used to accomplish this?

The fiddler trace indicates that the yahoo URL is calling:

the uiserver.php endpoint with the permissions.request method.

https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=permissions.request&app_id=194699337231859&display=iframe&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.login.yahoo.com%2Fopenid%2Fyrp%2Fsc_check&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.login.yahoo.com%2Fopenid%2Fyrp%2Fsc_check&perms=user_birthday%2Cuser_likes%2Cemail%2Cpublish_actions&response_type=code&locale=en_US

When i try to do this using FB's javascript SDK:
    FB.ui({ 
     method: 'permissions_request', 
     perms: 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos', 
     display: 'iframe' 
     },
    function(response){ 
      alert("badfood");
     alert(response); 
    });

It goes to a different endpoint: facebook.com/dialog/permissions_request? ...

And I get a 500 server error from facebook without useful debug info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

some things.

1) first add the parameter `show_error=true`. This will tell you more about what's really causing the error.

2) Facebook has multiple ways it can display any dialog. In the fiddler request, note the `display=iframe` parameter. This is used for canvas applications mainly but can be useful for regular iFrame displays as well. It opens the auth dialog in a lightbox.

3) Try loading the SDK synchronously. Remove the Async references that Facebook tells you to include at the top of the page after the body tag and use the secondary method. Include the `all.js` and `fb-root` div tag and load `FB.init` just before your `FB.ui` call.

4) Check out the [echo tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo).

> This tool can print out your GET params or your . It can also decode
>   the signed_request parameter as used in Canvas applications with the
>   OAuth 2.0 Beta migration enabled. This is very useful in debugging
>   Canvas Authentication.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: Thanks @Chamilyan, 

for 1) I tried adding show_error in fiddler and replaying and also adding it to my FD.ui parameter list. I dont see any additional error information beyong the HTTP Error 500.

Comment: For 2) I tried going through this documentation, but the initial OAuth dialog that asks for credentials (dialog/oauth endpoint) marks the X-Frame-Options: DENY in the response headers.

I havent found a way of splitting the request into two - one that asks you to login (which im ok with being a popup and not iframeable), and the permissions request (which i would like to customize by putting iframe around)

Comment: well if your not seeing the FB dialog at all and your getting a 500. Its probably a server side config problem.

Comment: Do you mean with my app or FB in general?
My apps config is quite simple. its a test app:



App ID/API Key

202489329832992 


App Secret

4632bb0e995708cce6ae204109202d1e 




App Namespace

manasamanam 


Site URL

http://www.elmo.com:4321/ 




Site Domain

elmo.com 


Contact Email

gswamina@gmail.com 




Support Email

gswamina@gmail.com 


App Description

Comment: im talking about your app. 500 server error means something is wrong with the server. Try removing all FB associations and load the page and see if your still getting it.

Comment: Im actually hosting it locally on my box with IIS and with the ipaddress mapping in hosts file. The pages load fine from browser. (Very basic hello world's + Facebook JS).

Also 500 server error is returned by the facebook URL, not my webserver's URL.

Comment: I added two more things you could try to help debug

Answer (score 0):

Loading the auth/permissions dialogs inside iframes are not permitted nor possible due to the risk of clickjacking. Sites where you see this being done have special agreements with Facebook that allows them to do this.